# android device not recognised

Tags: android

Hi all I am trying to add my motorola milestone device into PC and debug in the device. When i put the usb cable, the device opens in data storage mode and opens the folder. 
But when i do a "adb devices" i dont see any device.

i did the usb_driver fresh installation guide, but it returned "windows could not find a better driver than currently installed" I havd pointed to sdpath/usb_driver

what's wrong and how to resolve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the USB drivers from the usb_driver folder in your SDK (I guess you are using win. So e.g. C:\android-sdk-windows\usb_driver).

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the driver from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

And maybe also read the page on [Developing on a Device](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html).

Comment: I have followed these procedures already and it installs the usb driver telling motorola device installed, but i never get device in the device list when i execute adb devices